# How to create Indexes on Mysql test tables for Django Unittest

Tags: mysql, django, indexing, python-unittest

I am trying to create UnitTests for api which has django raw query. This raw query uses Force indexes.
While running test I am getting following error:

```
  File "/home/vagrant/.envs/django/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 114, in exe
cute
    return self.cursor.execute(query, args)
  File "/home/vagrant/.envs/django/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 205, in execute
    self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)
  File "/home/vagrant/.envs/django/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 36, in defaulterrorha
ndler
    raise errorclass, errorvalue
DatabaseError: (1176, "Key 'dBegDate_index' doesn't exist in table 't'")
```

here `t` is alias for my table.

Note: default database has all indexes. and This business logic API is working correct on default database.

So does that mean, For test database indexes are not setting? If not then how can i create indexes for test database in setUp()

Comment: How did you define the indexes in the first place? It should all be done via migrations.

Comment: @DanielRoseman  As i mentioned above in description, Business logic api is working fine, as its running on production Mysql tables, which has indexes set.

But now, i want to test this business logic api, for which i am not getting how to add indexes for tables in test db  created by Django unittests.

Comment: But how are you expecting your test db to know about indexes you have created directly in your production db? This is precisely what migrations are for, to define the db structure in code so that it is reproducible for all environments.

Comment: Indexes were applied explicitly on the db itself, I have not used migration for  this, not exactly the right way to do it.
so now I am stuck with this. Should I set indexes explicitly(raw sql) in the SetUp of the test ?